# Can't create class instances via hard coded data

Tags: list, class, flutter, dart, instance

Trying to create instances in order to pass data properly through the widget tree, I am starting with a list of list of strings/integers and will be creating a list of instances in which each index of the sublist is stored within the instance. Passing the hardcoded data manually into the class initializer is cumbersome, my data is already stored in a List and I've tried mapping and looping through the list but nothing seems to work. How can I automate creating class instances from an existing hardcoded data structure?

I ended up just coping the list to python and running a script to create strings which in dart would represent the class being initialized, from there i pasted the script out put into dart. But in the future I would like to go from hardcoded data to class instances without switching languages. Below is an example of what I tried in Flutter.

```
`
    Class Item{
    final String x;
    final int mula;
    Item(this.x, this.y)
    }

    var data = [["hog", 22]["meow", 55]];

    List<Item> = data.map((item)=> Item(item[0],item[1])).toList();
```

`
Should give output [Item(hog,22) etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some syntax errors like the `Class` (with capital C), instead of `class` and you are also missing a comma between the 2 sublists in your `data` list, and the class variables doesn't match with what you are passing in the constructor. Try something like the code bellow. You can test at [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/).

```
class Item {
  final String x;
  final int y;
  Item(this.x, this.y);
}

void main() {

  var data = [
    ["hog", 22],
    ["meow", 55]
  ];

  List<Item> listItem = [];
  
  data.forEach((item) {
    listItem.add(Item(item[0], item[1]));
  });

  print(listItem[0].x);

}
```